# Trying to understand docopt(__doc__)

Tags: python, sqlite, docopt

So I am trying to learn Python but I am a little bit overwhelmed with many new things.

One of these things that I am not able to understand is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
args = docopt(__doc__)
print(args)
```

The results of the **print** function is always:

```
{'initdb': False,
'run': False}
```

In some examples, the 'initdb' must be true in order to initialize the database and pretty much to run the app?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
args = docopt(__doc__)
if not args['initdb']:
   ...
```

How can I make the initdb value equals true?

This is my first attempt to learn the subject, apologies if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: `code.py -initdb`?

Comment: @internet_user I ran the app using `-initdb` and it gave me this result: `Usage: app.py [run] app.py initdb`

Comment: @internet_user I think to make `initdb` true, I need to run the command like this: `app.py initdb`

Comment: How does the program's docstring look?